# Decode Arabic to Arabic Presentation Form

Tags: code-golf, unicode

## Objective

Given an Arabic string consisting of ISO/IEC 8859-6 Arabic letters (U+0621–063A, 0640–064A), decode it to Arabic Presentation Forms-B (U+FE70–FEFF).

## Behavior of Arabic letters

ISO/IEC 8859-6 Arabic letters change their displayed form to letters in Arabic Presentation Forms-B, which are categorized to **isolated**, **initial**, **medial**, or **final** letters.

- If a letter is the first letter or follows another letter in isolated or final form:

  - If it is also the last letter or it lacks an initial form, it is in **isolated** form.
  - Otherwise, it is in **initial** form.
- Otherwise, if the letter is not the last letter, its medial form is available, and the next letter is not `ء`(U+0621), it is in **medial** form.
- Otherwise, the letter is in **final** form.
- `ـ` (U+0640) is a special case. It doesn't have a presentation form, and always will be mapped to itself. It will be assumed to appear only where a letter in medial form could appear.

Note that Arabic letters are written right-to-left.

## Mapping

[image: Arabic letters]

Note that we don't care about ligatures (U+FEF5–FEFC).

## Rule

If the string contains a letter not within U+0621–063A nor U+0640–064A, the challenge falls in *don't care* situation.

## Example

The following word:

```
الله (U+0627 U+0644 U+0644 U+0647)
```

is decoded to:

```
ﺍﻟﻠﻪ (U+FE8D U+FEDF U+FEE0 U+FEEA)
```

The following word:

```
تكبر (U+062A U+0643 U+0628 U+0631)
```

is decoded to:

```
تكبر (U+FE97 U+FEDC U+FE92 U+FEAE)
```

The following word:

```
سلـام (U+0633 U+0644 U+0640 U+0627 U+0645)
```

is decoded to:

```
ﺳﻠـﺎﻡ (U+FEB3 U+FEE0 U+0640 U+FE8E U+FEE1)
```

The following word:

```
شيء (U+0634 U+064A U+0621)
```

is decoded to:

```
ﺷﻲﺀ (U+FEB7 U+FEF2 U+FE80)
```

Comment: I think more test cases would be nice!

Comment: "Note that Arabic letters are written right-to-left." - does this affect the challenge? (The examples seem to have been treated left-to-right.)

Comment: When you say "first" and "last" is that with respect to the entire input string/list or a "word"? If the latter what splits words?

Comment: @JonathanAllan In the examples, the Arabic letters are written right-to-left, but the code points are written left-to-right. Since the string doesn't contain whitespaces, the string is a single "word."

Comment: @Arnauld All fixed.

Comment: Could you quite a few more test cases, especially for the special cases. Like one that contains `ـ` (U+0640) and two test cases with `ء` (U+0621): one before a medial form and one with `ء` (U+0621) somewhere else in the word. My current approach works for the two examples, but I haven't even implemented anything for these special cases yet.. Also, a test case where the last letter is a final form would also be useful.

Comment: May our code take and return a list of code points?

Comment: @Arnauld I'll permit it.

Comment: Is the rule about TATWEEL (U+0640) true? Shouldn't U+0640 followed by U+064B be mapped to U+FE71?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>110</s> 107 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
1ƵFLŽ$§R©+ε•7Ö›±ćY¨Γ∊%•ƵBвNåi1‚1ª]˜4ô®¸šIŽ6d-D₂›6*-èRćURviy2èDiyнsë0ëyθDΘIN>èŽ6dQ~i\y1è1ë0]Xs_i¦}н)IŽ6ηDŠkǝ
```

-3 bytes due to looser I/O rules.

I/O as a list of code-point integers.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/a/kmVdQWmKlgB0o2Xvacik5JpeUJuYoZIJUKiQWKyTnp6QW5GfmlRRbgZQcbrcNU/pveGyrm8/RvSqHlgcdWql9buujhkXmh6c9ath1aOOR9shDK85NftTRpQoUPbbV6cImv8NLMw0fNcwyPLQq9vQck8NbDq07tOPowsije81SdF0eNTUBNZpp6R5eEXSkPTSoLLPS6PAKl8zKC3uLD682OLy68twOl3MzIv3sDq8A6Qisy4ypNDy8whAoGRtRHJ95aFnthb2aINPObXc5uiD7@Nz/SnphcJ/kl5Zg8YqSPdCv/gipjMSixOSS1KJiK0RwHF6u8//GqpvNN1bc2AgA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TxqXkmVdQWmKlgB0o2Vfacik5JpeUJuYoZIJUKiQWKyTnp6QW5GfmlRRbgZQcbrcNU/pveGyrm8/RvSqHlgcdWql9buujhkXmh6c9ath1aOOR9shDK85NftTRpQoUPbbV6cImv8NLMw0fNcwyPLQq9vQck8NbDq07tOPowsije81SdF0eNTUBNZpp6R5eEXSkPTSoLLPS6PAKl8zKC3uLD682OLy68twOl3MzIv3sDq8A6Qisy4ypNDy8whAoGRtRHJ95aFnthb2aINPObXc5uiD7@Nz/SnphcJ/kl5Zg8YqSPdCv/gipjMSixOSS1KJiK0RwHF6uw3Vom/3/G8tvtgBhO9eNVTebb6y4sZHrxmYgvwEo3sp1Y8vNrhsLuRCyC4HyNxugPKCijQA).

**Explanation:**

```python
1                   # Push a 1 (which we'll use later on)
```

We start by creating the lookup table:

```python
 ƵF                 # Push compressed integer 116
   L                # Pop and push a list in the range [1,116]
    Ž$§             # Push compressed integer 25156
       R            # Reverse it to 65152
        ©           # Store this value in variable `®` (without popping)
         +          # Add it to each value in the list, to make the range [65153,65268]
ε                   # Map each value to:
 •7Ö›±ćY¨Γ∊%•       #  Push compressed integer 35731296019285847629599
             ƵB     #  Push compressed integer 112
               в    #  Convert the larger integer to base-112 as list:
                    #   [1,3,5,7,13,19,41,43,45,47,109,111]
 Nåi                #  If the map-index is in this list:
    1‚1ª            #   Pair it with a 1, and add a second 1 to this list
]˜                  # Close the map and if-statement, and flatten the list of values
  4ô                # Split it into parts of size 4
    ®¸š             # Prepend [65152] (from variable `®`) in front of this list
```

Which will now hold the following list:

```python
[[65152],[65153,65154,1,1],[65155,65156,1,1],[65157,65158,1,1],[65159,65160,1,1],[65161,65162,65163,65164],[65165,65166,1,1],[65167,65168,65169,65170],[65171,65172,1,1],[65173,65174,65175,65176],[65177,65178,65179,65180],[65181,65182,65183,65184],[65185,65186,65187,65188],[65189,65190,65191,65192],[65193,65194,1,1],[65195,65196,1,1],[65197,65198,1,1],[65199,65200,1,1],[65201,65202,65203,65204],[65205,65206,65207,65208],[65209,65210,65211,65212],[65213,65214,65215,65216],[65217,65218,65219,65220],[65221,65222,65223,65224],[65225,65226,65227,65228],[65229,65230,65231,65232],[65233,65234,65235,65236],[65237,65238,65239,65240],[65241,65242,65243,65244],[65245,65246,65247,65248],[65249,65250,65251,65252],[65253,65254,65255,65256],[65257,65258,65259,65260],[65261,65262,1,1],[65263,65264,1,1],[65265,65266,65267,65268]]
```

Which corresponds to the following table:

```python
ISO 8859-6   Isolated      Final         Initial       Medial
1569[0621]   65152[FE80]
1570[0622]   65153[FE81]   65154[FE82]   1[n\a]        1[n\a]
1571[0623]   65155[FE83]   65156[FE84]   1[n\a]        1[n\a]
1572[0624]   65157[FE85]   65158[FE86]   1[n\a]        1[n\a]
1573[0625]   65159[FE87]   65160[FE88]   1[n\a]        1[n\a]
1574[0626]   65161[FE89]   65162[FE8A]   65163[FE8B]   65164[FE8C]
1575[0627]   65165[FE8D]   65166[FE8E]   1[n\a]        1[n\a]
1576[0628]   65167[FE8F]   65168[FE90]   65169[FE91]   65170[FE92]
1577[0629]   65171[FE93]   65172[FE94]   1[n\a]        1[n\a]
1578[062A]   65173[FE95]   65174[FE96]   65175[FE97]   65176[FE98]
1579[062B]   65177[FE99]   65178[FE9A]   65179[FE9B]   65180[FE9C]
1580[062C]   65181[FE9D]   65182[FE9E]   65183[FE9F]   65184[FEA0]
1581[062D]   65185[FEA1]   65186[FEA2]   65187[FEA3]   65188[FEA4]
1582[062E]   65189[FEA5]   65190[FEA6]   65191[FEA7]   65192[FEA8]
1583[062F]   65193[FEA9]   65194[FEAA]   1[n\a]        1[n\a]
1584[0630]   65195[FEAB]   65196[FEAC]   1[n\a]        1[n\a]
1585[0631]   65197[FEAD]   65198[FEAE]   1[n\a]        1[n\a]
1586[0632]   65199[FEAF]   65200[FEB0]   1[n\a]        1[n\a]
1587[0633]   65201[FEB1]   65202[FEB2]   65203[FEB3]   65204[FEB4]
1588[0634]   65205[FEB5]   65206[FEB6]   65207[FEB7]   65208[FEB8]
1589[0635]   65209[FEB9]   65210[FEBA]   65211[FEBB]   65212[FEBC]
1590[0636]   65213[FEBD]   65214[FEBE]   65215[FEBF]   65216[FEC0]
1591[0637]   65217[FEC1]   65218[FEC2]   65219[FEC3]   65220[FEC4]
1592[0638]   65221[FEC5]   65222[FEC6]   65223[FEC7]   65224[FEC8]
1593[0639]   65225[FEC9]   65226[FECA]   65227[FECB]   65228[FECC]
1594[063A]   65229[FECD]   65230[FECE]   65231[FECF]   65232[FED0]
1601[0641]   65233[FED1]   65234[FED2]   65235[FED3]   65236[FED4]
1602[0642]   65237[FED5]   65238[FED6]   65239[FED7]   65240[FED8]
1603[0643]   65241[FED9]   65242[FEDA]   65243[FEDB]   65244[FEDC]
1604[0644]   65245[FEDD]   65246[FEDE]   65247[FEDF]   65248[FEE0]
1605[0645]   65249[FEE1]   65250[FEE2]   65251[FEE3]   65252[FEE4]
1606[0646]   65253[FEE5]   65254[FEE6]   65255[FEE7]   65256[FEE8]
1607[0647]   65257[FEE9]   65258[FEEA]   65259[FEEB]   65260[FEEC]
1608[0648]   65261[FEED]   65262[FEEE]   1[n\a]        1[n\a]
1609[0649]   65263[FEEF]   65264[FEF0]   1[n\a]        1[n\a]
1610[064A]   65265[FEF1]   65266[FEF2]   65267[FEF3]   65268[FEF4]

not in the list:
1600[0640]                                             1600[0640]
```

After that, we'll use the input to get a quartet from this list:

```python
I                   # Push the input-list of codepoint integers
 Ž6d                # Push compressed integer 1569
    -               # And subtract it from each integer in the list
     D              # Duplicate this list
      ₂›            # Check which are larger than 26 (1 if truthy; 0 if falsey)
        6*          # Multiply that by 6 (6 if truthy; 0 if falsey)
          -         # And subtract that from the values in the list as well
           è        # Then index it into our list of quartets
```

And now we apply the rules specified in the challenge description on these quartets of `[isolated, final, initial, medial]`.

```python
R                   # Reverse the list
 ć                  # Extract the head; pop and push remainder-list and head separated
  U                 # Pop the head, and store it in variable `X`
                    # (`X` now holds the last letter)
   R                # Reverse the list back
v                   # Loop `y` over each remaining quartet:
 i                  #  If the top of the stack is 1 (it's an isolated or final form):
                    #  (which is always truthy for the first letter, since we pushed a 1 at the start)
  y2è               #   Get the initial form of `y`
     D              #   Duplicate it
      i             #   If it's 1, thus no initial form is available:
       yн           #    Push the isolated form of `y` instead
         s          #    And swap so the 1 is at the top for the next iteration
      ë             #   Else, thus an initial form is available:
       0            #    Push a 0 for the next iteration
 ë                  #  Else (it's an initial or medial form instead):
  yθ                #   Get the medial form of `y`
    DΘ              #   Duplicate it, and 05AB1E-truthify it (1 if 1; else 0)
    I               #   Push the input-list of codepoints again
     N>             #   Use the loop-index+1
       è            #   To index into this list for the next letter codepoint
        Ž6d         #   Push compressed integer 1569
           Q        #   And check if this next codepoint is equal to it (1 if truthy; 0 if falsey)
            ~i      #   If either of the two checks is truthy:
              \     #    Discard the duplicated medial form that's on the stack
               y1è  #    Get the final form of `y`
                  1 #    And push a 1 for the next iteration
             ë      #   Else (it's a medial, and the next character is NOT `ء` (U+0621)):
              0     #    Push a 0 for the next iteration
]                   # Close the loop and all inner if-else statements
 X                  # Push the last letter from variable `X`
  s_i               # If we ended with a 0 (thus an isolated or medial form)
     ¦              #  Remove the first item from `X`
    }н              # After the if-statement: pop and push the first item of `X`
                    # (so the isolated form if we ended with an isolated or final form,
                    #  or the final form if we ended with an initial or medial form)
)                   # Wrap all values on the stack into a list
 I                  # Push the input-list of codepoints again
  Ž6η               # Push compressed integer 1600
     DŠ             # Duplicate it, and triple swap (`®`,1600,1600 to 1600,`®`,1600)
       k            # Get the index of 1600 inside the codepoints list (-1 if not present)
        ǝ           # And insert the 1600 at that index in our created list
                    # (which doesn't work on negative indices)
                    # (after which this list of codepoint integers is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (sections *How to compress large integers?* and *How to compress integer lists?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `ƵF` is `116`; `Ž$§` is `25156`; `•7Ö›±ćY¨Γ∊%•` is `35731296019285847629599`; `ƵB` is `112`; `•7Ö›±ćY¨Γ∊%•ƵBв` is `[1,3,5,7,13,19,41,43,45,47,109,111]`; `Ž6d` is `1569`; or `Ž6η` is `1600`.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>231 ... 148</s>  146 bytes

I/O format: list of code points

```javascript
a=>a.map(t=(c,i)=>c%32?(g=A=>n^c%49?g([x=n%32<26,k*x,x&=454642>>n++*25%54%26,x].map(x=>x&&++k)):A[t=t>1^2*(a[i+1]>1569)]||A[t^=2])(n=k=0)+65151:c)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBPS8MwGMbv/RShsDVZa1hrW9hmMsbw4ElheCodhKzbuj9paTMpOEFQEfwWnhRvoh@m@zQzXXcZmByS53neN7y/LNgdy3kWp/JMJJNoPyV7RijDa5ZCSSC3YkQob5w7fTgjA0LFmDfcTn8Gg4IIZV84vrVsFVbRJK7n@q5DqTDNluM1PLehsiI8PFUQWjSbprlEqDsIJJHUHjstyILYtENqe34HhdutSsbECREUZEnayPQ927O7HO0nm3UKCIAylqvIAjkChIJ7wBORJ6sIr5JZHQETGF1gqCNHvZM4wBjn9Sy8auaYK9ybJBZyICHCMhnJLBYzaPuVuE3TKBuyPFJRyiYjyTIJXQsYbQMhvFBt0ADq2gMPmhZoAOjlx@5Z7VfdOqiv3VP5WX4f1Y9KHlXFy1H/7t7Kd10LNTxNskvG5zCviSpQqF@JdCOBbh0oaut6I5WnrHpMPM2S9XDOsqGigIpt@h/hMa8Aq3X6I9XsaP8H)

```javascript
a =>                             // a[] = input array
a.map(t = (c, i) =>              // for each code point c at position i in a[]:
  c % 32 ?                       //   if c is not 0x0640:
    ( g = A =>                   //     g is a recursive function taking a list A[]
        n ^ c % 49 ?             //       if we haven't reached the correct character:
          g(                     //         do a recursive call:
            [                    //           build a list describing the existence of:
              x = n % 32 < 26,   //           - isolated: if not in range 0x063B-0x0640
              k * x,             //           - final: same as isolated, except for the
                                 //             first entry which is undefined
              x &=               //           - initial: we use a lookup bit-mask
                454642 >> n++    //             with the following hash formula:
                * 25 % 54 % 26,  //               ((n * 25) mod 54) mod 26
              x                  //           - medial: same as initial
            ].map(x => x && ++k) //           turn it into a list of indices
          )                      //         end of recursive call
        :                        //       else:
          A[                     //         output the relevant entry from A[]:
            t =                  //           update t:
              t > 1 ^ 2 * (      //             (previous was initial or medial) XOR
                a[i + 1] > 1569  //             2 * (this is not the last letter 
              )                  //             and the next letter is not 0x0621)
          ] ||                   //         if A[t] is not defined:
            A[t ^= 2]            //           use A[t ^ 2] instead
    )(n = k = 0)                 //     initial call to g with n = k = 0
    + 65151                      //     add 0xFE7F
  :                              //   else:
    c                            //     output c unchanged
)                                // end of map()
```